# Crash when using ofstream

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, ofstream

I have a problem with the following code. I would like to write out data into different files in a loop. But when I instantiate ofstreams in a loop, my program silently crashes. I've boiled the code down, so that it doesn't do anything useful. It just demonstrates the behavior that I cannot explain:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ofstream test_a("a.json");
  cout << "test a" << endl;
  
  ofstream test_b("b.json");
  cout << "test b" << endl;
  
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)     
     {
       cout << "test " << idx << endl;
       ofstream test("test_" + to_string(idx) + ".json");
     }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
test a
test b
test 0
```

Nothing else, no error, nothing.

The first two ofstreams are apparently fine, but the loop stops somewhere after the cout. I am using Windows 10 and mingw:

```
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Comment: Could you wrap the loop by an exception handler in order to printout the crash reason?

Comment: Side question, probably unrelated to the problem - I'm assuming `to_string` is the function defined in `#include <string>`, right?

Comment: The only issue visible is that the header file `<string>` is not imported which is needed for the `to_string` function.
After adding `#include <string>` to your code, it worked without errors.

Comment: You guys are right, <string> should be included, but it compiles without it. How can that be? But I found what's causing the behavior. This is how I compile: C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -lstdc++ -O3 magnet_circuit.cpp -o magnet_circuit.exe. It's the -O3 that's causing the problem. Without it, it runs fine. I also added a try..catch, but that does nothing.

Comment: There are some specific cases where some standard headers are required (by the standard) to implicitly include (declarations from) some headers.  But the standard doesn't *forbid* other standard headers from including each other.  In practice, it is reasonably common for `<iostream>` to `#include <string>`, although that is not required by the standard - and your usage of `to_string` would work with those particular compilers/libraries.   The catch is that there are other implementations where `<iostream>` does not include `<string>`, and your code will not compile with them.

Comment: You should not add `-lstdc++`, the compiler knows how to link the standard library so just remove this flag.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the helpful comments I found that I linked a std library that must have been from an older version of my compiler. I fixed that and now it works.